How to find integer index of a string in a column in pandas dataframe?
I am importing a csv file in pandas containing data like this. Referring to following code,  I want to get integer index of row containing name_to_search in column name in df1.
name, ColB, ColC, ColD
P1, 1,1,1
P2, 0,1,0
P3, 1,1,0
...

df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='file.csv', header=[0])
df1['name'].str.lower()
name_to_search = 'p1'

row_indx1 = df1.index.get_loc(df1[df1['name'] == name_to_search].index[0])  # error line

However, I am getting error IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 in error line row. Any idea how to fix?

If default index use next with iter, with default value if no match, here -1:
name_to_search = 'p1'
row_indx1 = next(iter(df1[df1['name'].str.lower() == name_to_search].index), -1)
print (row_indx1)
0

name_to_search = 'tmp'
row_indx1 = next(iter(df1[df1['name'].str.lower() == name_to_search].index), -1)
print (row_indx1)
-1

Or compare indices, faster if large DateFrames:
row_indx1 = next(iter(df1.index[df1['name'].str.lower() == name_to_search]), -1)


Any idea what is going wrong in original code?

First problem is no assigned back lowercase values, so compared P2:
df1['name'].str.lower()
print (df1['name'])
0    P1
1    P2
2    P3
Name: name, dtype: object

Second problem is if no match, is not possible select first index values of empty DataFrame and IndexError raised.
print (df1[df1['name'] == name_to_search])
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, ColB, ColC, ColD]
Index: []

print (df1[df1['name'] == name_to_search].index)
Index([], dtype='int64')

print (df1[df1['name'] == name_to_search].index[0])
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

If default index Index.get_loc return same value, it is used for position of non RangeIndex:
print (df1.index.get_loc(2))
2

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(3)}, index=['E','W','T'])
print (df)
   a
E  0
W  1
T  2

print (df.index.get_loc('E'))
0


Thanks. Any idea what is going wrong in original code?

@ewr3243 - Added to answer.

Build a Series/dictionary of your indices with the values to search as index and use get with a default value in case there is no match:
name_to_search = 'p1'

s = pd.Series(df1.index, index=df['name'].str.lower())
# or with a dictionary
s = dict(zip(df1.index, df['name'].str.lower()))

s.get(name_to_search, None)
# 0

s.get('x', None)  # None is the default
# None

Then you can use a conditional:
if (i:= s.get(name_to_search)) is not None:
    # do something with i
else:
    # optionally do something else


Using np.where
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

text_ = '''name, ColB, ColC, ColD
P1, 1,1,1
P2, 0,1,0
P3, 1,1,0'''

df1 = pd.read_table(StringIO(text_), sep = ',', lineterminator='\n')
df1['name'] = df1['name'].str.lower()
print(df1)

name_to_search = 'p1'
row_indexes = np.where(df1['name'] == name_to_search)[0]

print(f'Label index: {df.index[row_indexes]}')
print(f'Position index: {row_indexes}')

result should be:
  name   ColB   ColC   ColD
0   p1      1      1      1
1   p2      0      1      0
2   p3      1      1      0

Label index: Index([0], dtype='int64')
Position index: [0]

